# When I have tried to run maze_solver code im not getting the output, how do I get the expected output?

Tags: python

```
N = 4

def printSolution( sol ): 
    
    for i in sol: 
        for j in i: 
            print(str(j) + " ", end ="") 
        print("") 


def isSafe( maze, x, y, visited): 
    
    if x >= 0 and x < N and y >= 0 and y < N and maze[x][y] == 1 and visited[x][y] == True: 
        return True
    
    return False


def solveMaze( maze ): 
    
    sol = [ [ 0 for j in range(4) ] for i in range(4) ] 
    visited = [ [ 0 for j in range(4) ] for i in range(4) ]
    
    if solveMazeUtil(maze, 0, 0, sol, visited) == False: 
        print("Solution doesn't exist")
        print(-1)
        return False
    
    printSolution(sol) 
    return True
    
def solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y, sol, visited): 
    if x == N - 1 and y == N - 1 and maze[x][y]== 1: 
        sol[x][y] = 1
        return True
        
    
    if isSafe(maze, x, y, visited) == True:
        sol[x][y] = 1
        if solveMazeUtil(maze, x + 1, y, sol, visited) == True:
            visited[x][y] = True 
            return True
        if solveMazeUtil(maze, x - 1, y, sol, visited) == True:
            visited[x][y] = True
            return True
                
        if solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y - 1, sol, visited) == True:
            visited[x][y] = True
            return True
        if solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y + 1, sol, visited) == True: 
            visited[x][y] = True
            return True
        
        
        

        sol[x][y] = 0
        return False

    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    
    maze = [ [1, 0, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 0, 1], 
            [0, 1, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 1, 0] ] 
            
    solveMaze(maze)
```

Comment: Please read about [ask] and hpw tp provide a [mre]. Just throwing in some code is not an appropriate question... Please mention if you get an error or an unexpected output. In case of the latter, provide an example input (if applicable) and the output you get together with the output you expected

Comment: Actually the expected output is "path not found" -1, but I'm getting a 4*4 matrix with all the element as 0's. If I give a valid path as input like [ [1,0,0,0], [1,1,0,0], [1,0,1,0], [1,1,1,1] ], in this case also I'm getting the same output as a 4*4 matrix with all element as 0's. I think there is some issue with the "visited[x][y]" , how can resolve the issue?

Comment: @AyushSingh https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-rat-in-a-maze-backtracking-2/ Use that example, same as what you are attempting.

Comment: @ Raymond Thanks. How can I keep a note of visited blocks and how can I implement if it is allowed to move in all directions?

Answer (score 1):

The following slight changes to your code allows it to work.

Made comments in code to highlight changes.

**Code**

```
# N = 4 -- removed (get dimension of maze using len function) 

def printSolution( sol ): 
    
    for i in sol: 
        for j in i: 
            print(str(j) + " ", end ="") 
        print("") 

def isSafe( maze, x, y, visited): 
    N = len(maze)      # Get Maze dimensions (N x M) rather than hardcoding using N as a global
    M = len(maze[0])
    
    # x, y safe to use if not visited (original code had visited)
    #if x >= 0 and x < N and y >= 0 and y < N and maze[x][y] == 1 and visited[x][y] == True: 
    # Can simplify x >= 0 and x < N to 0 <= x < M
    return 0 <= x < N and 0 <= y < M and maze[x][y] == 1 and not visited[x][y]

def solveMaze( maze ): 
    N = len(maze)      # Get Maze dimensions (N x M) rather than hardcoding using N as a global
    M = len(maze[0])
    sol = [ [ 0 for j in range(M) ] for i in range(N) ] 
    visited = [ [ 0 for j in range(M) ] for i in range(N) ]
    
    if not solveMazeUtil(maze, 0, 0, sol, visited): # preferred to checking for False
        print("Solution doesn't exist")
        print(-1)
        return False
    
    printSolution(sol) 
    return True
    
def solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y, sol, visited): 
    N = len(maze)      # Get Maze dimensions (N x M) rather than hardcoding using N as a global
    M = len(maze[0])
    
    if x == N - 1 and y == M - 1 and maze[x][y]== 1: 
        sol[x][y] = 1
        return True
        
    if isSafe(maze, x, y, visited): # preferred to checking for True
        sol[x][y] = 1         # Try solution from current x, y position
        visited[x][y] = True  # Mark as visited so no other soltuion will use it
        
        # Recursive calls to solveMazeUtil can be simplfied to the following:
        if (solveMazeUtil(maze, x + 1, y, sol, visited) or 
            solveMazeUtil(maze, x - 1, y, sol, visited) or 
            solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y - 1, sol, visited) or 
            solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y + 1, sol, visited)):
            return True   # Found a solution
        else:
            sol[x][y] = 0 # Couln't use x, y in solution
        return False
    else:
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    print("Test 1")
    maze = [ [1, 0, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 0, 1], 
            [0, 1, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 1, 0] ] 
    solveMaze(maze)
    
    print("\nTest 2")
    maze = [ [1, 0, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 0, 1], 
            [0, 1, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 1, 1] ] 
    solveMaze(maze)
    
    print("\nTest 3")
    maze = [ [1, 0, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 0, 1], 
            [0, 1, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1]] 
    solveMaze(maze)
```

**Output**

```
Test 1
Solution doesn't exist
-1

Test 2
1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0 
0 1 1 1 

Test 3
1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0 
0 1 1 1
```

**OO Version**

```
class Maze:
  def __init__(self, maze):
    # Constructor
    self.maze = maze

  def size(self):
    # Tuple for Maze dimensions
    return len(self.maze), len(self.maze[0])

  def isSafe(self, x, y, visited):
    '''
      Checks if okay to select cell x, y
    '''
    # Get Maze dimensions (N x M)
    N, M = self.size()

    # x, y safe to use if not visited (original code had visited)
    #if x >= 0 and x < N and y >= 0 and y < N and maze[x][y] == 1 and visited[x][y] == True: 
    # Can simplify x >= 0 and x < N to 0 <= x < M
    return 0 <= x < N and 0 <= y < M and self.maze[x][y] == 1 and not visited[x][y]

  def solveMaze(self):
    '''
       Controlling function for Maze solver
    ''' 
    # Get Maze dimensions (N x M)
    N, M = self.size()

    sol = [ [ 0 for j in range(M) ] for i in range(N) ] 
    visited = [ [ 0 for j in range(M) ] for i in range(N) ]
    
    if not self.solveMazeUtil(0, 0, sol, visited): # preferred to checking for False
      print("Solution doesn't exist")
      print(-1)
      return False
    
    self.printSolution(sol) 
    return True

  def solveMazeUtil(self, x, y, sol, visited): 
    '''
      Recursive Maze solver
    '''
    # Get Maze dimensions (N x M)
    N, M = self.size()
    
    if x == N - 1 and y == M - 1 and self.maze[x][y]== 1: 
        sol[x][y] = 1
        return True
        
    if self.isSafe(x, y, visited): # preferred to checking for True
        sol[x][y] = 1         # Try solution from current x, y position
        visited[x][y] = True  # Mark as visited so no other soltuion will use it
        
        # Recursive calls to solveMazeUtil can be simplfied to the following:
        if (self.solveMazeUtil(x + 1, y, sol, visited) or 
            self.solveMazeUtil(x - 1, y, sol, visited) or 
            self.solveMazeUtil(x, y - 1, sol, visited) or 
            self.solveMazeUtil(x, y + 1, sol, visited)):
            return True   # Found a solution
        else:
            sol[x][y] = 0 # Couln't use x, y in solution
        return False
    else:
        return False

  def printSolution(self, sol ): 
    '''
      Format and print solution
    '''
    for i in sol: 
      for j in i: 
          print(str(j) + " ", end ="") 
      print("") 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    print("Test 1")
    maze = Maze([ [1, 0, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 0, 1], 
            [0, 1, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 1, 0] ])

    maze.solveMaze() 
    
    print("\nTest 2")
    maze = Maze([ [1, 0, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 0, 1], 
            [0, 1, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 1, 1] ])
    maze.solveMaze() 
    
    print("\nTest 3")
    maze = Maze([ [1, 0, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 0, 1], 
            [0, 1, 0, 0], 
            [1, 1, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1]])
    maze.solveMaze()
```

*Output*

Same as non-OO version

Comment: @AyushSingh--glad to help. Were the suggestions clear?

Comment: @DarryIG , Thank you for clear explanation, I really appreciate.

Comment: @AyushSingh--glad to help.  If it solves your problem you should [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so others know the question has been solved.

Comment: @DarryIG, how can I implement oops concept like class and objects to this program, i'm really confused,? thank you

Comment: @DarryIG, I'm stuck actually I'm a begineer

Comment: @AyushSingh--are you familiar with classes on a basic level?

Comment: @DarryIG, yes I am

Comment: @AyushSingh--thought I was alerted that you were having trouble running the program but I can't find the comment. Perhaps you deleted it since things are okay.  If not, let me know.

Comment: @DarryIG, thank you so much for helping me out, I was really stuck.

Comment: @DarryIG, how can I use command line parameters like import argparse and read and write input and output, using that give user input on powershell and get user output as .txt file.

Comment: @AyushSingh--I haven't used argparse myself, but [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/03/12/python-argparse-command-line-arguments/) I think reads and writes files getting parameters from argparse.

Comment: @DarryIG, yes you are correct. I have checked with video lectures and notes and will give a try. Thanks for your response. I really appreciate your help.